# Type-Error when trying to saving with VB script

Tags: string, vbscript, save, filenames, typeerror

I am trying to use the following script and it is giving me a type error on the following bold line of code.

```
 Option Explicit

 Dim xlApp
 Dim xlBook
 Dim Filename
 Dim Format

 Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
 Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("\\denfs1\home\davidvan\desktop\shane spread sheet 2.xlsm", 0, True)

 xlApp.Run "Mail_Body"
 **xlBook.SaveAS Filename=("H:Contrabutions spread sheet" & Format(Date,"MM/DD/YYYY")& ".xlsm")**
 xlBook.close
 xlApp.Quit


 Set xlBook = Nothing
 Set xlApp = nothing
```

I feel like i need to define the filename as a string but am unsure how to do that with out makeing an error

Answer (score 1):

1. There is no Format() function in VBScript (as opposed to VBA), look up FormatDateTime() instead
2. There are no named parameters in VBScript (and the syntax in VBA involves a ":="), use a plain string as first parameter to the .SaveAs method
3. The VBScript parser needs no spaces around the string concatenation operator